# read xml in reverse order using xsl

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, reverse

I tried searching and getting this working but I failed. Can some one help me to get a proper XSL file to get me XML nodes in reverse order

My XML file looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='ResultXSL.xsl'?>
<Automation>
<Run>
<client1>
  <Date>25/02/2014</Date>
  <TotalTests>23</TotalTests>
  <Success>13</Success>
  <Failures>10</Failures>
</client1>
<client2>
  <Date>25/02/2014</Date>
  <TotalTests>4</TotalTests>
  <Success>0</Success>
  <Failures>4</Failures>
</client2>
<client3>
  <Date>25/02/2014</Date>
  <TotalTests>9</TotalTests>
  <Success>3</Success>
  <Failures>6</Failures>
</client3>
</Run> 
<Run>
<client1>
  <Date>26/02/2014</Date>
  <TotalTests>23</TotalTests>
  <Success>13</Success>
  <Failures>10</Failures>
</client1>
<client2>
  <Date>25/02/2014</Date>
  <TotalTests>4</TotalTests>
  <Success>0</Success>
  <Failures>4</Failures>
</client2>
<client3>
  <Date>25/02/2014</Date>
  <TotalTests>9</TotalTests>
  <Success>3</Success>
  <Failures>6</Failures>
</client3>
</Run>
<Run>
<client1>
  <Date>27/02/2014</Date>
  <TotalTests>23</TotalTests>
  <Success>13</Success>
  <Failures>10</Failures>
</client1>
<client2>
  <Date>25/02/2014</Date>
  <TotalTests>4</TotalTests>
  <Success>0</Success>
  <Failures>4</Failures>
</client2>
<client3>
  <Date>25/02/2014</Date>
  <TotalTests>9</TotalTests>
  <Success>3</Success>
  <Failures>6</Failures>
 </client3>
 </Run>
 </Automation>
```

I need the RUN node to be printed in reverse order. Currently I have XSL to print it in correct order.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"      xmlns:TESA="tesa.philips.com">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <hr/>
    <p>
      <table border="5"  cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" width="1200">
        <tr>
          <th style="font-weight:bold;background:#a6caf0;width:350px;height:80">Date</th>
          <th style="font-weight:bold;background:#a6caf0;width:350px">Total Tests</th>
          <th style="font-weight:bold;background:#a6caf0;width:350px">Passed</th>
          <th style="font-weight:bold;background:#a6caf0;width:350px">Failure</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="Automation/Run">
          <tr>
            <td class="cellTextLeft">
              <xsl:value-of select="client1/Date"/>
            </td>
            <td class="cellTextLeft">
              <xsl:value-of select="client1/TotalTests"/>
            </td>
            <td class="cellTextLeft">
              <xsl:value-of select="client1/Success"/>
            </td>
            <td class="cellTextLeft">
              <xsl:value-of select="client1/Failures"/>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="cellTextLeft">
              <xsl:value-of select="client2/Date"/>
            </td>
            <td class="cellTextLeft">
              <xsl:value-of select="client2/TotalTests"/>
            </td>
            <td class="cellTextLeft">
              <xsl:value-of select="client2/Success"/>
            </td>
            <td class="cellTextLeft">
              <xsl:value-of select="client2/Failures"/>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="cellTextLeft">
              <xsl:value-of select="client3/Date"/>
            </td>
            <td class="cellTextLeft">
              <xsl:value-of select="client3/TotalTests"/>
            </td>
            <td class="cellTextLeft">
              <xsl:value-of select="client3/Success"/>
            </td>
            <td class="cellTextLeft">
              <xsl:value-of select="client3/Failures"/>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr style="background:Gray">
            <td style="height:20"> - </td>
            <td></td>               
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </table>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
    <xsl:for-each select="Automation/Run">
      <xsl:sort select="position()" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
      <tr>
        <td class="cellTextLeft">
          <xsl:value-of select="client1/Date"/>
        </td>
```

instead of

```
    <xsl:for-each select="Automation/Run">
      <tr>
        <td class="cellTextLeft">
          <xsl:value-of select="client1/Date"/>
        </td>
```

Comment: Can we modify this to show only last 10 entries (latest entries) in the XML? Is that achievable using XSL?

Comment: Ask a new question please, stating clearly whether you want the last 10 entries of the input or of the reversed order or based on some date value in the input.

Answer (score 2):

try this stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:TESA="tesa.philips.com">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30" />
            </head>
            <body>
                <hr/>
                <p>
                    <table border="5"  cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" width="1200">
                        <tr>
                            <th style="font-weight:bold;background:#a6caf0;width:350px;height:80">Date</th>
                            <th style="font-weight:bold;background:#a6caf0;width:350px">Total Tests</th>
                            <th style="font-weight:bold;background:#a6caf0;width:350px">Passed</th>
                            <th style="font-weight:bold;background:#a6caf0;width:350px">Failure</th>
                        </tr>
                        <xsl:for-each select="Automation/Run">
                            <xsl:for-each select="*">
                                <xsl:sort select="name()" order="descending"/>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="cellTextLeft">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="current()/descendant::Date"/>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="cellTextLeft">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="current()/descendant::TotalTests"/>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="cellTextLeft">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="current()/descendant::Success"/>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="cellTextLeft">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="current()/descendant::Failures"/>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                            <tr style="background:Gray">
                                <td style="height:20"> - </td>
                                <td></td>               
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </table>
                </p>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```